# What's the best practice for working with pure JS modules from typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I am trying to use the [react-console-emulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-console-emulator) component in a TypeScript project.

When I try to import it:

```
import Terminal from 'react-console-emulator';
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-console-emulator'.
 '.../dist/Terminal.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-console-emulator` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-console-emulator';`
```

So what I understood is that the issue here is that `Terminal.js` probably does not have types declared, and this is causing the issue.

What's the best practice for dealing with this situation?  I really just want an escape-hatch for being able to use this component in my JSX.

From the error it looks like I can use the .d.ts file, but is this the best way?

Comment: Hi have you tried this? https://medium.com/@steve.mu/create-a-decleration-file-d-ts-file-a-npm-module-does-not-have-type-package-e986faae1c15

Answer (score 0):

The common approach to solving this is to create a file somewhere in the root of your codebase, for example `global.d.ts` with your own custom-made typings for the lib:

```
declare module 'react-console-emulator' {
  const emulator: React.Component<{ 
    contentStyle?: React.CSSProperties; 
    style?: React.CSSProperties; 
    inputAreaStyle?: React.CSSProperties; 
    promptLabelStyle?: React.CSSProperties; 
    inputStyle?: React.CSSProperties; 
    inputTextStyle?: React.CSSProperties; 
  }>;
  export default emulator;
}
```

However, as you see, you'll have to describe the type shape of the value on your own.

UPD: I added some of the props you might expect to see in that lib, but you need to make sure you have the ones there that correspond to the version of the lib you use.

Comment: Is there any kind of escape hatch for the properties?  I.e. a way to just say the JSX should accept any properties?